# How to utilise the white space in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to swiftUI and I am facing this Issue as shown in the screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqFVF.png)

I am using a list to display my data and NavigationLInk to pass my data to next ViewController.

My Code -
{

```
    NavigationView{
        
      
            List( bookListViewModel.bookListingViewModel, id: \.self) { dataToDisplay in
                HStack{
                   
                    Text(dataToDisplay.titleName)
                   
                    NavigationLink(
                    destination: BookDetail(id: dataToDisplay.id)) {
                    }
                 
               
           }
        
            }.onAppear{
                self.bookListViewModel.BookList()
            }
    
        .navigationTitle("Book List")
    }
    

}
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Can you show what code you have currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Text` can go *inside* the `NavigationLink` -- the `NavigationLink` takes a label parameter inside the trailing closure (`{ }`) that you currently have empty. You don't need the `HStack` either:

```
NavigationView {
  List(bookListViewModel.bookListingViewModel, id: \.self) { dataToDisplay in
    NavigationLink(destination: BookDetail(id: dataToDisplay.id)) {
      Text(dataToDisplay.titleName)
    }
  }.onAppear{
    self.bookListViewModel.BookList()
  }
  .navigationTitle("Book List")
}
```